# What is the Most Efficient Java-Based streaming XSLT Processor?

Tags: java, xslt, processor

I have a very large XML file which I need to transform into another XML file, and I would like to do this with XSLT. I am more interested in optimisation for memory, rather than optimisation for speed (though, speed would be good too!).

Which Java-based XSLT processor would you recommmend for this task?

Would you recommend any other way of doing it (non-XSLT?, non-Java?), and if so, why?

The XML files in questions are very large, but not very deep - with millions of rows (elements), but only about 3 levels deep.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**At present there are only three [XSLT 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/) processors known** and from them [**Saxon 9.x**](http://www.saxonica.com) is probably the most efficient (at least according to my experience) both in speed and in memory utilisation. **[Saxon-SA](http://www.saxonica.com)** (the schema-aware version of Saxon, not free as the B (basic) version) has special extensions for streamed processing.

**From the various existing** **[XSLT 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)** processors, .NET **[XslCompiledTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.aspx)** (C#-based, not Java!) seems to be the champion.

**In the Java-based world of XSLT 1.0 processors** **[Saxon 6.x](http://www.saxonica.com)** again is pretty good.

**UPDATE**:

Now, since 2017 **we have XSLT 3.0 and Saxon10/11 is still my choice.**

Comment: It's a year later, and Dimitre's comment still stands. In fact, Saxon has gotten faster.

Comment: XSLT 3 streaming is definitely the way to go.  Thanks for keeping this answer up to date, Dimitre.

Comment: It looks like XSLT 3 has been officially released in the 2017-version.  https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/

Answer (score 9):

You could consider [STX](http://stx.sourceforge.net/), whose Java implementation is [Joost](http://joost.sourceforge.net/). Since it is similar to XSLT, but being a stream processor it is able to process enormous files using very little RAM.

Joost is able to be used as a standard javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory

Comment: This project seems dead.  I tried their latest (2009) release.  It didn't go down to well with my 452GB XML file, also it lacks UTF-8 support

Comment: Joost is dead. I'm working on a project which uses Joost. It works fine except that when we attempto upgrade Joost dependencies (XML parsing), it breaks. This is causing major headaches. Don't use Joost.

Answer (score 4):

See Saxon support for streaming mode. http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/streaming/

If this streaming mode isn't for you, you can try to use [tiny tree mode](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sourcedocs/choosingmodel.html) of Saxon, which is optimized for smaller memory usage. (It is default anyway)