# What XSLT processor should I use for Java transformation?

Tags: java, xslt

What XSLT processor should I use for Java transformation? There are SAXON, Xalan and TrAX. What is the criteria for my choice? I need simple transformation without complicated logical transformations. Need fast and easy to implement solution. APP runs under Tomcat, Java 1.5.
I have some jaxp libraries and could not understand what is the version of jaxp used.


Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The JDK comes bundles with an internal version of Xalan, and you get an instance on it by using the standard API (e.g. `TransformerFactory.newInstance()`).

Unless Xalan doesn't work for you (which is highly unlikely), there's no need to look elsewhere.

By the way, TrAX is the old name for the `javax.xml.transform` API, from the days when it was an optional extension to the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's a hard question to answer because it heavily depends what you mean by "simple transformation" and "fast", as well as the amount of XML you want to process. There are probably other considerations as well. To illustrate, "fast" could mean "fast to write" or "fast to execute", if you process files the size of available memory you might make a different choice (maybe STX, as described in another SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460895/what-is-the-most-efficient-java-based-xslt-processor)) than if you parse small files etc.

Comment: I parse small files but recently enough