# Streaming XML through Transformation into JAXB Unmarshaller, with a declared class type for the root element

Tags: java, jaxb

There are many examples of **streaming XML** through the XSLT, then JAXB into Java objects. Often they look like this:

```
Transformer responseTransformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("ResponseTransformation.xsl")));
Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName()).createUnmarshaller();

JAXBResult jaxbResult = new JAXBResult(jaxbUnmarshaller);
responseTransformer.transform(new StreamSource(new StringReader(responseXml)), jaxbResult);
res = jaxbResult.getResult();
```

There are also examples of JAXB Unmarshal by **declared type** like this (from Unmarshaller javadoc):

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo" );
Unmarshaller u = jc.createUnmarshaller();

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(new File( "nosferatu.xml"));
Element  fooSubtree = ...; // traverse DOM till reach xml element foo, constrained by a 
                           // local element declaration in schema.

// FooType is the JAXB mapping of the type of local element declaration foo.
JAXBElement<FooType> foo = u.unmarshal(fooSubtree, FooType.class);
```

Note how we specifying FooType.class for the root element in `u.unmarshal(fooSubtree, FooType.class)` call. Nice.

**The question is:** Is there a way to combine the streaming way of processing as in the top example with a way of specifying the declared type as in the example below?

I fond a way of achieving it, but it requires accessing JAXB implementation classes. Surely it is possible to do it via public JAXB interface, right?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get access to the unmarshaller.unmarshal(source, type) methods by creating an XMLFilter.  This code will allow you to run a transform and unmarshal into an object that is not bound to a root element in an XSD:

```
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLFilter;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBResult;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXSource;
import javax.xml.transform.sax.SAXTransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import static org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly;
...
InputStream transformIn = null;
InputStream sourceIn = null;

try {
  // get the transform and source streams.
  transformIn = ...;
  sourceIn = ...;

  // create the filtered source
  SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory)TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  XMLFilter filter = factory.newXMLFilter(new StreamSource(transformIn));
  Source source = new SAXSource(filter, new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(sourceIn, "UTF-8")));

  // unmarshal the object.
  Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = 
    JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class.getPackage().getName()).createUnmarshaller();
  JAXBElement<FooType> foo = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(source, FooType.class);
}
finally {
  closeQuietly(transformIn);
  closeQuietly(sourceIn);
}
```

**WARNING**: Just because you are using a streaming API does not mean that the implementation is streaming.  Most XSLT processors will build a DOM style representation of the input before transforming the document.  If you are trying to avoid building the document before unmarshalling, this code may not do that.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/461661/1818625) for more information about processors.