# Flatten the xml file

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

I want to write a generic xml parser which can flatten any xml file. e.g.

if the xml has structure  like :

```
<A a="a1">

   <B> b </B>

   <C>

      <D> d1 </D>

      <D> d2 </D>

   </C>

   <C>

      <D> d3 </D>

   </C>

   <E> e1 </E>     

</A>
```

I should get the output like :

a1 b  d1 e1

a1 b  d2 e1

a1 b  d3 e1

I want the parser to be generic so that it could be applied to any xml without the knowledge of the tags. I have heard of XSLT. But I am not sure whether we can write a generic XSL w/o the knowledge of xml tags. XML files can be size of ~ 1Gb. 
Is there a generic soln for this problem?

Comment: xslt require the entire document to be loaded into memory before it performs the transformation. Thats a large memory footprint. Have you looked into SAX?

Comment: yes i know abt SAX parser. But I am stuck at not being able to flatten the nested xmls without having any prior information of any xml tags, even the root tag.

Comment: @ColinD Usually Xslt processors support streaming so you would not have to load the entire document into memory. See [What is the Most Efficient Java-Based XSLT Processor](http://stackoverflow.com/q/460895/205233).

Comment: @user1397016 Using Xslt would't that much require knowledge of the actual tags but of the structure - you can achieve pretty much just using [Location Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256039).

Comment: @Filburt streaming xslt is a feature being considered for the next versions of xsl spec (2.0+). I would imagine most processors who do streaming now, only do it in specific instances, so I am not sure it can be relied on.

Comment: Steaming processor is of no help here, because the XML format clearly allows unlimited number of elements with the same name and their values should be combined with all values of elements with other names. A streaming transformation needs only limited memory for its execution and this problem clearly violates this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SAX parser, and keep a stack of open elements. Upon seeing elements open, add them to the stack. On text nodes, print the stack, and on closing elements, pop them off the stack. Should be straightforward.

Comment: I dont think the soln u gave will give the desired output.. can you run your logic over the case i presented and see if it gives the same output. The logic of yours wont repeat the parent elements . Correct me if I am mistaken somewhere !

Comment: Well, specify your output properly, not with an example! In your case, B and E are *not* parent elements!

Answer (score 0):

The "flattening" you seem to want is more of an "explosion".  Your input is a tree and you want to explode this into a set of records with all redundant data repeated.  This is NOT a job for XSLT.  Conceptually you have to make multiple passes over the data. First you must identify all leaf-node collections at all levels; then you have to run through all possible combinations of leaf nodes, outputting a complete set of data for EACH combination.  If your input is ~1GB, be prepared for terabytes of output.

It looks like you have two choices:

1. Use SAX to load the entire tree into memory, then implement the explosion algorithm.
2. Make a pass over the input data to extract the structure and establish the position cursors on each leaf-node set; then make multiple passes over the input, using the cursors to decide what to output on each pass.

Either way, I'm not sure what you've described is actually what you want.  For any large, multi-level set of leaf nodes the number of combinations could easily become astronomical.